# Example of sheaf cohomology

Tags: complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

> Suppose $X$ is a compact complex surface,
> $$
> X=\mathbb{C}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}/\sim,
> $$
> where the relation is $(z_1,z_2)\sim(2z_1,2z_2)$.
> Compute $H^0(X, \mathscr{O}), H^2(X, \mathscr{O}),H^1(X, \mathscr{O}), H^0(X, \mathscr{O}^*)$.

I just read the Appendix of *Complex Geometry_An Introduction* by Huybrechts. I wonder how to compute a concrete example of sheaf cohomology.